# Reference initializer not rejected in template class

Tags: c++, templates, initializer-list

In the following template class definition, why is the initializer not rejected?

```
#include <cstdlib>

template <size_t S>
struct Have_ref {
    Have_ref(int& x, int(&arr)[S]) : x{x}, arr{arr} {};
    int& x{}; // compiles in VS2015 and gcc. Rejected by Clang
    int(&arr)[S] {}; // compiles in VS2015, gcc and Clang
};

//struct Have_ref2 {
//  Have_ref2(int& x, int(&arr)[5]) : x{x}, arr{arr} {};
//  int& x{}; // error: invalid intitialization
//  int(&arr)[5] {}; // error: invalid initialization
//};

int main()
{
    int x{};
    int arr[5];
    Have_ref<5>{x,arr};
}
```

Comment: If you change code so that those initializations take place, gcc reports error (no vs to test for it). So I would say it is just a miss to diagnostic a possible problem.

Comment: gcc also reports error when removing the template.

Comment: I'm thinking maybe the implicit constructors are created before the template parameters are substituted and by then the initializers had already been removed or replaced as needed.